# HTML img tag src issue

Tags: html, image, src

I am having a problem referencing an image I have on a server in my temp folder. I have the following:

```
 <a href="#" title="Hello">
     <img width="220" height="255" src="file://myServerName/c$/temp/myImage.jpeg" class="attachment-hp-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Hello" />
 </a>
```

This is currently giving me a blank screen, no errors. Can someone please give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot local stuff from a `file:` url if the containing page was loaded via something OTHER than file, e.g. `http://`. to allow this would be a major security/privacy vulnerability.

Comment: Oh ok.... what would be the best way to do this then?

Comment: Is your index (html) file saved on the server also?

Comment: Run a web server in your network that can return this file. Maybe IIS is already running on that server?

Comment: Put the image with your hosted website in a content/images folder and use a relative URL to it

Comment: put the file on your server. or at least somewhere you can get at it via http.

Comment: @GolezTrol IIS? Are you using this "service"? Oh my god.

Comment: Thank you all, will run on web server

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I don't know what you mean. I just see a UNC path to a file on a Windows server, so I thought IIS might already be available, in which case it is good enough to server that file. Installing Apache on Windows for this purpose is overkill and also not a great solution. But of course, if you like you can also setup a redundant LAMP environment with a load balancer...

Comment: I see a classname of wordpress and I think in PHP. Think in PHP + IIS destructs my brain. Think in Microsoft web development destructs my brain and my body. Sorry if I disturb you with this.